# Send multiple $scope. json values with $http.post to php page

Tags: php, angularjs, xml

Im tryng to insert ino mysql db json data passed with $http.post angularjs.
The problem is that i would send $scope.data taken from $http.get call and $scope.reg taken by form compiled!

Im tryng so:

```
$http.post('/contabilita/fatture/archivio/prova.php', $scope.items, $scope.reg)
            .success(function(data){.....
```

but send only first $scope!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. send object with all ur params.
var data= {items:$scope.items, reg:$scope.reg};

$http.post('/contabilita/fatture/archivio/prova.php', data)
            .success(function(data){..